# Oracle Regex expression to match exactly non digit then digits again

Tags: regex, oracle

How can a phone number (or any number) be regex'ed in Oracle to be exactly the correct length followed by a non-digit and then potentially digits again?

e.g.

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 
  REGEXP_LIKE('555-5555x123', '^[0-9]{3,4}[^[:digit:]][0-9]{4}.*$')
```

Where the number 555-5555 would be ok, 555-5555x123 would be ok, but 555-5555123 would not.

What can happen is someone with fat fingers is typing a phone number and makes a mistake by adding extra numbers (please don't say the input format should be restricted, it's not my data) and this should be flagged as a problem.  The example is then more like 555-55545x123.

Test Cases for Oracle REGEXP_LIKE
    Value         Result
    555-5555      ok
    555-5555x123  ok
    555-55551x123 fail
    555-55551     fail
    555-5555555   fail

Comment: Why would `555-5555x123` be OK?

Comment: 555-5555x123 would be ok because the phone number portion before the x is well defined and I can be sure it is at least the correct length.  With 555-55545x123 I know something is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `.*` at the end of your expression it is responsible for matching the additional stuff.

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 
  REGEXP_LIKE('555-5555x123', '^[0-9]{3,4}[^[:digit:]][0-9]{4}$')
```

That way it does match 3 or 4 digits, a non digit and 4 more digits.

The `{3,4}` and `{4}` are the quantifiers that define the amount of digits you want to allow. Just change them to the values you need. E.g. `{4,}` would match 4 or more.

`^` anchors the regex to the start of the string and `$` to the end.

**Update**

To ensure that there is a non digit after the 4 digits at the end you can use an alternation

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 
  REGEXP_LIKE('555-5555x123', '^[0-9]{3,4}[^[:digit:]][0-9]{4}($|[^0-9].*$)')
```

Now, after your 4 digits there must be either the end of the row OR a non digit (`[^0-9]` is a negated character class), then anything (but newlines) till the end of the row.

I don't know if it is important in your case, but `[^0-9]` would also match a newline character, if you want to avoid this use `[^0-9\r\n]`

Comment: But the rest of the number is important because I need it to validate that the phone number is the correct length and is not too long.  I've added a clearer function result to the question

Comment: brilliant, that's it ($|[^0-9].*$)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT regextestcol FROM regexptest WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(address,'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}(\w\d{3})?$');
```

Description:

- `^` start of your search pattern
- `[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}` matches three and four digit numbers separated by hypen
- `(\w\d{3})?` matches a word , a three digit number which both can be optional together with `?` sign
- `$` end of your search pattern